# Disable SMS Logging

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to disable, or constantly be clearing, Twilio's SMS logging feature?  I can understand how most people would be thrilled to have a log of all incoming and outgoing SMS messages in the Twilio console, but for what I'm building this won't be kosher.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely delete messages so that they are no longer stored on Twilio. Check out the documentation for how to do so here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#instance-delete

Here's how you'd do it with curl:

```
curl -X DELETE "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{Your Account Sid}/Messages/{Message SID}" -u "{Your Account Sid}:{Your Auth Token}"
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: So is there no way to disable logging?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you meant the messages themselves. You can disable the logging of requests by [following these instructions](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-do-i-prevent-twilio-from-logging-twiml-for-data-compliance-requirements).

Comment: It says that's for voice though. It doesn't say anything about SMS.

Comment: Oh man, you're right, I'm sorry! I wasn't paying attention! I guess with SMS the only log is that of the message itself. My guess is that we've never built the option to disable that because most people would want the messages stored in case they miss the incoming message. In this case, you'll have to clear them out yourself using the DELETE method in the API. You could set up to do that as soon as you receive the incoming webhook so that you can clear them out as they arrive yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [philnash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28376/philnash)'s answer, you cannot currently disable SMS logging for your Twilio account, but deleting the message resource also deletes the associated log record. You can choose to selectively delete parts of the message content (for instance, if you want to redact the message body, but want to keep the message record itself intact), or delete the entire record.

To selectively "delete" fields (pedantically, update the field value to be an empty string), you can follow [these examples given by Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/11/introducing-delete-api-nt.html), such as this `curl` request to delete the entire body of a message:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{Your Account Sid}/Messages/{Your Message Sid}" -d "Body=" -u "{Your Account Sid}:{Your Auth Token}"
```

Or you can use this modified request to delete the entire message resource:

```
curl -X DELETE "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{Your Account Sid}/Messages/{Your Message Sid}" -u "{Your Account Sid}:{Your Auth Token}"
```

When you selectively delete fields, your log record will show a record of when the message record was updated. If you delete the message entirely, Twilio will respond with `204 NO CONTENT` to indicate success, and subsequent requests to the deleted resource will respond with a `404 NOT FOUND`. Check out the full [message resource documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) for more information.

**Bonus note:** If message body redaction is your main concern, [Twilio is currently testing a built in feature to do this automatically](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/increase-sms-privacy-with-message-body-redaction.html).